# Flutter : How to Calculate total price of a List of items in FutureBuilder

Tags: flutter, dart

How to Calculate total price of a List of items in `FutureBuilder` ?
i try this

```
FutureBuilder<ProModel>(
  future: futurePro,
  builder: (context, snapshot){
  if(snapshot.hasData){
    snapshot.data.pro.forEach((element) {
    subTotal = subTotal + int.parse(element.amount);
    });
  }
}
```

but `subTotal` in a continuous increasing (to infinity) when i add  `Text('$subTotal')`
snapshot.data.pro is list from json

```
{
"pro":[
  {"id":"1", "amount":"1784",}
  {"id":"2", "amount":"1643",}
 ]
}
```

Comment: can you what the snapshot.data looks like, and the proModel implementation

Comment: @Gwhyyy  ProModel get data from api (http.get) and snapshot.data has data like id,items as List named "pro" and each items have a amount and id

Comment: can you include a simple example for that pro list

Comment: and I added the solution in your case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are storing the `subTotal` somewhere in the surrounding widget.

As any build method, your builder callback can be called multiple times and is adding to the stored value every time it is called. So instead of

```
snapshot.data.pro.forEach((element) {
  subTotal = subTotal + int.parse(element.amount);
});
```

you can try to store the value in a local variable like this:

```
var subTotal = 0;
for (var p in snapshot.data.pro) {
  subTotal += int.parse(p.amount);
}
```

Comment: Nice to hear that. You still might want to check for unnecessary rebuilds in your widget. "Counting up to infinity" sounds like some other issue exists with your surrounding widgets. Put a print in the builder or check out Flutter's Repaint Rainbow to debug it.

Comment: okay roger that

Answer (score 0):

in your case, this line:

```
subTotal = subTotal + int.parse(element.amount);
```

exactly in this `element.amount`, you're trying to get the non existing `amount` property that doesn't exists in the elements of your `list`, what you have is a `List<Map>` and the `amount` key of a `Map` can be called only like this `element[amount]`.

so in your case, replace with this:

```
 if(snapshot.hasData){
snapshot.data.pro.forEach((element) {
subTotal = subTotal + int.parse(element["amount"]);
});
 }
```

Comment: subTotal It keeps increasing to infinity , it is not stop

Comment: I tried to simulate the code in a gist, https://gist.github.com/anasfik/484dcfb5b2084d47335c424efdca0c9a take it and try it on dartpad.dev

Comment: is there anything different from what your code is doing, and the gist's code

Comment: if run function in FutureBuilder the result is different , subTotal not stop it keeps increasing

Comment: then I guess you have other problems with your code, can you include the futurePro method, with your variable initialisations